# How can I SELECT the row with max value?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select NATIONALPLAYERS.FIRSTNAME||' '|| NATIONALPLAYERS.LASTNAME as PlayerName, NATIONALPLAYERS.EXPERIENCEID, experience

from NATIONALPLAYERS

INNER JOIN (select experienceid, MAX( experiences.nationalgames + experiences.internationalgames ) as experience

from experiences 

group by experiences.EXPERIENCEID)plexperience
 on plexperience.experienceid = NATIONALPLAYERS.experienceid;
```

This displays all the records from `PlayerName`, `ExperienceID`, and `Experience` even though I asked only for the maximum value of `experience`.

Comment: You have asked for first name, last name, experience id & experience. That's what it would give!

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `EXPERIENCEID` and getting the maximum `EXPERIENCE` for each of those - you are not finding the `EXPERIENCEID` which corresponds to the maximum `EXPERIENCE`.

If you want to find the values for the maximum experience then you want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select n.FIRSTNAME ||' '|| n.LASTNAME as PlayerName
         n.experienceid,
         e.nationalgames + e.internationgames as Experience
  from   NATIONALPLAYERS n
         INNER JOIN
         EXPERIENCE e
         ON ( e.experienceid = n.experienceid )
  ORDER BY Experience DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

or, if there are multiple highest rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select n.FIRSTNAME ||' '|| n.LASTNAME as PlayerName
         n.experienceid,
         e.nationalgames + e.internationgames as Experience,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY e.nationalgames + e.internationgames DESC )
           AS rn
  from   NATIONALPLAYERS n
         INNER JOIN
         EXPERIENCE e
         ON ( e.experienceid = n.experienceid )
  ORDER BY Experience DESC
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the max experience. You are checking the experience_id but not making sure that the experience value is the max value

The query should be something like:

```
SELECT 
    NATIONALPLAYERS.FIRSTNAME||' '|| NATIONALPLAYERS.LASTNAME as PlayerName, 
    NATIONALPLAYERS.EXPERIENCEID, 
    experience

from NATIONALPLAYERS
INNER JOIN (
    select 
        experienceid, 
        MAX( experiences.nationalgames +     experiences.internationalgames ) as experience

    from experiences 
    group by experiences.EXPERIENCEID) AS plexperience
 on 
    plexperience.experienceid = NATIONALPLAYERS.experienceid
    **plexperience.experience = NATIONALPLAYERS.experience;**
```

Comment: This is still getting the maximum `EXPERIENCE` for **each** `EXPERIENCEID` and not the `EXPERIENCEID` which has the maximum `EXPERIENCE`.